# Does a Filipino citizen with Swedish Permanent Residency need a visa to visit Bulgaria?

Tags: visas, europe, filipino-citizens, bulgaria

Does a citizen of the Philippines with Swedish Permanent Residency need a visa to visit Bulgaria? They will be traveling with their spouse, whom is a Swedish citizen.

Comment: If I understand correct https://mfa.bg/en/services-travel/consular-services/travel-bulgaria/visa-bulgaria they need a visa. The visa-free regime is for Schengen visa holders, and also for holders of  valid visas and residence permits issued by Romania, Cyprus and Croatia. But not for holders of residence permits issued by a Schengen country.

Answer (score 1):

According to Timatic, the system used by airlines, your residence permit means you can visit without a visa:

“The following are exempt from holding a visa:

- Passengers with a residence permit issued by Sweden for a maximum stay of 90 days”

Source: https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b